# How can you output a list in a more English form (like "a, b and c")?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a list but, when printing, I need to add the 'and' right before the last item in the list. Example:

```
mylist = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']
```

When I print out the list I want it to look like:

```
me, you, him and her.
```

I don't want the `'`, `[` or `]` to show.

I'm currently using:

```
mylist = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']
print (','.join.(mylist))
```

but the output is `me,you,him,her`. I need it to show `me, you, him and her`.

Comment: `', '.join(mylist[:-1]) + ' and ' + mylist[-1]`

Comment: @LoMaPh: What about `['me']` or `[]`?

Comment: @Sergey Good point!

Comment: If you liked one of these answers, would you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.join` twice with `rsplit`:

```
mylist = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']

new_str = ' and '.join(', '.join(mylist).rsplit(', ', 1))
print(new_str)
```

Output:

```
me, you, him and her
```

This works fine with empty or single-element list:

```
new_str = ' and '.join(', '.join([]).rsplit(', ', 1))
print(new_str)
# None

new_str = ' and '.join(', '.join(['me']).rsplit(', ', 1))
print(new_str)
# me
```

Comment: That doesn’t work where the last item contains a comma. `[“once”, “twice”, “three times, a lady“]` should become `“once, twice and three times, a lady”`. Yours would render that as `“once, twice, three times and a lady”`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of explicitness, so I might write this like:

```
def human_list(items):
    # Empty list? Empty string.
    if not items:
        return ''

    # One-item list? Return that item.
    if len(items) == 1:
        return items[0]

    # For everything else, join all items *before* the last one with commas,
    # then add ' and {last_item}' to the end.
    return ', '.join(items[:-1]) + ' and ' + items[-1]

# Demonstrate that this works the way we want
assert human_list([]) == ''
assert human_list(['spam']) == 'spam'
assert human_list(['spam', 'eggs']) == 'spam and eggs'
assert human_list(['one', 'two', 'three']) == 'one, two and three'
assert human_list(['knife', 'fork', 'bottle', 'a cork']) == 'knife, fork, bottle and a cork'
```

Comment: that's the way you spell New York ... like your test driven answer!

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen I'm so happy someone caught that. 

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
mylist = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']
length = len(mylist)
for i,j in enumerate(mylist):
    if i == length-2:
        print(j,'and ',end='')
    elif i == length-1:
        print(j,end="")
    else:
        print(j,end=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

A helper function is probably a good way to go since it centralises control at one point, meaning you can fix bugs or make improvements easily (such as handling edge cases like empty lists). It also makes the main code easier to read since it simply contains something like `readableList(myList)`.

The following function is all you need:

```
def readableList(pList):
    if len(pList) == 0: return ""
    if len(pList) == 1: return pList[0]
    return ", ".join(pList[:-1]) + ' and ' + pList[-1]
```

For a test harness, you can use something like:

```
for myList in [['me', 'you', 'him', 'her'], ['one', 'two'], ['one'], []]:
    print("{} -> '{}'".format(myList, readableList(myList)))
```

which gives the output:

```
['me', 'you', 'him', 'her'] -> 'me, you, him and her'
['one', 'two'] -> 'one and two'
['one'] -> 'one'
[] -> ''
```

Note that those quotes to the right of `->` are added by my test harness just so you can see what the string is (no trailing spaces, showing empty strings, etc). As per your requirements, they do *not* come from the `readableList` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a simple method if you don't want to go with slicing etc. It will allow you to reuse the functionality implemented (function calling) and also you can easily change the logic inside.

> *Note:* If list is empty, a blank string will be returned

```
def get_string(l):
    s = ""
    index = 0
    length = len(l)

    while index < length:
        word = l[index]

        if index == length - 1:
            s += 'and ' + word
        else:
            s += word + ", "

        index += 1

    return s.strip()


# Try
mylist = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']
print(get_string(mylist)) # me, you, him, and her
```

Answer (score -1):

To add an element before the last element you can do this

```
last_element = mylist.pop()
mylist.append(' and ')
mylist.append(last_element)
my_string = ', 'join(mylist[:-2]) + mylist[-2] + mylist[-1]
print(my_string)
```

or

```
mylist.insert(-1, ' and ')
my_string = ', 'join(mylist[:-2]) + mylist[-2] + mylist[-1]
print(my_string)
```

But a better answer as given by LoMaPh in the comments is:

```
', '.join(mylist[:-1]) + ' and ' + mylist[-1]
```

Comment: Agree best answer is by LoMaPh. However it does show how to insert an element before the last element though :)

Comment: Fun fact: you can use negative indexes (indices?) with `insert` so there's a much easier way to insert an element in a list before the last: `mylist.insert(-1, 'hello')`